# Java Jface cant be imported

Tags: java, swt, jface

Im trying to make a simple wizard in Java. After some research SWT with Jface seems like the way to go. I imported SWT into my project and all works fine. But as soon as I try to import something from Jface like:

```
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog;
import org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow;
import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog;
```

I get an error saying:

> The import org.eclipse.jface cannot be resolved`

Now I came across this guide on using Jface and I followed the steps:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace#Create_the_Eclipse_SWT.2FJFace_Project

At step 14 in the guide they want me to extend my ECLIPSE_HOME with plugins from the plugins directory. But this directory is empty besides for 1 file called: `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar`

I have been trying things for over a day now. Does anyone might know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You probably have an installation using Eclipse Oomph which puts plug-ins in a different location. Look in the `.eclipse` and `.p2` directories in your home directory.

Comment: pfff `.p2/pool/.plugins` Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin folder of eclipse oomph is a different directory:
`.p2/pool/.plugins`